# AFNetworking & Cloudflare Returning 503

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, cloudflare

I'm working on an app for a website that has CloudFlare enabled. This means at random times that I have no control over, the website will check to confirm that the browser the user is using is real by executing a JavaScript snippet and redirecting to the intended page. This process can take anywhere from 1-5 seconds to execute and AFNetworking doesn't execute JavaScript code, nor does it wait for CloudFlare to do its thing.

Currently I'm just sending the username and password to the website via POST, but it's always returning a 503 (Service Unavailable) code. What can I do to ensure AFNetworking can verify itself with CloudFlare without the owner of the website doing any extra work?

Comment: Do you get any solution, we are redirecting our webservices from our website which is hosted on another server to cloud flare, now we are calling the services from mobile application which are in response giving us the html page instead of giving the api response.

Answer (score -1):

My advise is to whitelist your IP Address in CloudFlare. To do this, select your site in the CloudFlare admin panel, select Firewall > IP Firewall. Then simply whitelist your IP under Access Rules by adding it there (make sure to select whitelist instead of block).

Comment: "without the owner of the website doing any extra work"

Comment: You need to be able to manage your intermediary provider (CloudFlare), otherwise you're essentially asking how to hack CloudFlare into whitelisting your IP.